# Facebook application has been stopped working on android emulator?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, emulation

When i try to open the facebook application after installing on my android emulator(API 17 intel*86),it shows "Unfortunately facebook has stopped". I need to work with the facebook application on my emulator to integrate Facebook api on my application? Can anyone suggest how to run the facebook application successfully on android emulator.

Comment: "I need to work with the facebook application on my emulator to integrate Facebook api on my application?" -- no, you should be able to test the integration on your Android device. I am not aware that Facebook makes their app available for installation on emulators.

Comment: We do ship a downloadable apk with every SDK release, but I believe that's only built for ARM and not *86 processors. So use an emulator that's ARM.

Comment: I tried installing using ARM but the installation process never ends up, nor the apk is installed.

Comment: I tried android 5.0.1 API 21 (arm v7a) and installed the facebook application on the emulator successfully.Thanks everyone for the reply